# R where to install packages properly?

Tags: r

I was usually using a pathway like:

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\beata\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpUDvn3Y\downloaded_packages

But I have recently read that it might be not wise to install them in the C:\Users\beata...

What would be your advice, where ti install packages?
and how to use projects?
should the packages I use to be saved within the project?

I am using R studio for easy and nice view...

help! please help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing within the default location?  Here's mine:

C:\Program Files\R\R-3.6.1\library\

Comment: yes, I was always doing it with default settings, recently I had problems with installing gbiplot, and I have seen criticism about the ...users.... pathway location. So I have checked mine and it's like I have cited. Maybe I should manually change the location?

Comment: also I don't really know why it matters where they are installed, and I have found for example on data camp that they also have the pathway with users name. So I wanted to ask stackoverflow opinion on this